# reactivate virtualenv when returning to a project the next day

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am new to django i started a project in a virtualenv then shutdown the computer when I was done for the day. so How do I return to the same virtualenv the next day to continue with the project?

Comment: `source venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: Which editor are you using? For PyCharm, it is enabled by default and you might need to manually enable in the others. Please specify

Comment: I am using visual studio code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the directory where you install virtual environment previously. To activate the virtual environment:

For MAC/Unix:

```
        your-enb-name/source/activate
```

For Windows:

```
       your-enb-name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

For more info visit [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Comment: Thank you it worked after I opened the editor and enabling the environment on it first, I don't know why though I could not do it before opening the IDE first.